# Python ValueError: non-hexadecimal number found in fromhex() arg at position 1

Tags: python, pandas, hex

Trying to Decode the following Hex Code to Ascii

> j
>   =['0x00003A01C01173D676B644D4E040DB9CC01173D676B62069311401000009416E64726F69644150010882848B962430486C32040C12186030140100000FAC040100000FAC040100000FAC020C002D1A2C0103FF00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000DD070050F2020001007F0400000A02']

```
 hex_to_ascii = bytes.fromhex(j)
```

the following is throwing an error - ValueError: non-hexadecimal number found in fromhex() arg at position 1

if any one can help with issue.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to remove first `0x` from the string:

```
j =['0x00003A01C01173D676B644D4E040DB9CC01173D676B62069311401000009416E64726F69644150010882848B962430486C32040C12186030140100000FAC040100000FAC040100000FAC020C002D1A2C0103FF00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000DD070050F2020001007F0400000A02']

hex_to_ascii = bytes.fromhex(j[0][2:])

print(hex_to_ascii)
```

This prints:

```
b'\x00\x00:\x01\xc0\x11s\xd6v\xb6D\xd4\xe0@\xdb\x9c\xc0\x11s\xd6v\xb6 i1\x14\x01\x00\x00\tAndroidAP\x01\x08\x82\x84\x8b\x96$0Hl2\x04\x0c\x12\x18`0\x14\x01\x00\x00\x0f\xac\x04\x01\x00\x00\x0f\xac\x04\x01\x00\x00\x0f\xac\x02\x0c\x00-\x1a,\x01\x03\xff\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xdd\x07\x00P\xf2\x02\x00\x01\x00\x7f\x04\x00\x00\n\x02'
```

Comment: i am getting output as b' ' in python 3.6

Comment: @BikiranDas b'' stands for bytes. That means you have decoded string with hexadecimal values to bytes.